# On-click menu - stay visible

Tags: html, css

I have a responsive (HTML/CSS) "hamburger" menu when the size of screen is below 768px.
Clicking on the hamburger the menu appears, but it won't stay visible. Any ideas on how to keep it visible so that one can click on the links of the menu?

CSS

```
    nav {
    float:right;
    padding:25px 20px 0px 0px;
}
#menu-icon {
    display:hidden;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    background: url(img/icons/nav-dark.png) center;
}
ul {
    list-style:none;
}
nav ul li {
    font-family: 'verdana', sans-serif;
    font-size: 150%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
}
nav ul li a{
    color:#6991AC;
}
.current {
    color:#F0F;
}
a:hover {
    color:#A5BDCD;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    #menu-icon {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    nav ul, nav:active ul {
        display:none;
        z-index:1000;
        position:absolute;
        padding:20px;
        background:#F5F5F5;
        border:1px solid #A5BDCD;
        right:20px;
        width:50%;
        border-radius:3px 0 3px 3px;
        opacity:.95;
    }

    nav li {
        text-align:center;
        width:100%;
    }
            nav:active > ul {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
    <header>


  <nav>

        <a href="#" id="menu-icon"></a>
    <ul class="main">
                    <li><a href="index.html" class="current">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Skills</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Our Team</a></li>
                    <li><a href="survey.html">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>

            </nav>
     </header>
```

Comment: jsfiddle please?

Comment: jsfiddle ? It's a HTML/CSS only menu, no Javascript.

Comment: So..? You can create jsfiddles with html/css to show a demo of the problem. Makes it easier and more convenient for people to aid you

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow ;) please check my answer. if i solved your issue, mark as the right answer. http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you schould use :focus instead of :active.. and you have to select the "hamburger" not the whole nav.

here is my solution:

```css
nav {
  float: right;
  padding: 25px 20px 0px 0px;
}

#menu-icon {
  display: hidden;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: url(img/icons/nav-dark.png) center;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

nav ul li {
  font-family: 'verdana', sans-serif;
  font-size: 150%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: #6991AC;
}

.current {
  color: #F0F;
}

a:hover {
  color: #A5BDCD;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #menu-icon {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .main {
    display: none;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #F5F5F5;
    border: 1px solid #A5BDCD;
    right: 20px;
    width: 50%;
    border-radius: 3px 0 3px 3px;
    opacity: .95;
  }
  nav li {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #menu-icon:focus ~ .main {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <a href="#" id="menu-icon">#</a>
    <ul class="main">
      <li><a href="index.html" class="current">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Skills</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Our Team</a></li>
      <li><a href="survey.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

View this solution in a Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/smwn4sdg/

> an other solution providing close-on-click: https://jsfiddle.net/smwn4sdg/1/

Note: Just remove the "#" of the "burger"... i've used it because jsfiddle dosn't know your image ;)

EDIT:

adding this to your css makes your links clickable, too:

```
  .main:hover {
    display: block !important;
  }
```

New Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/smwn4sdg/3/

Comment: Wow, thanks J. Sadi. It does work, the menu stays open. However, there is still a small issue, when I click on the "contact", it should open a separate page but it doesn't. Is there something missing?  You can try by substituting the current link to any URL, such as www.ibm.com. It just won't go there.